# Seeing Red/White checkerboard pattern in Civ V

Tags: civilization-5, graphics-card

I am getting a red/white checkerboard pattern with Civ 5. I understand this can happen if some particular video "effect" is not supported. What could be the effect here? How can I further diagnose this problem?

[image]

Note that it appears on the "city" view. The map view appears correctly.

Comment: It probably means some graphics asset didn't load correctly. If you get it every time you play, even after rebooting, trying verifying your game is installed correctly: https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2037-QEUH-3335

Comment: Also try disabling mods if you have any installed. If that fixes it, one of them is the problem.

Answer (score 6):

I eventually found out that the game was "missing assets", meaning textures and images it needed because not all the necessary files were downloaded. By "verifying" my steam installation, it updated the needed assets and the problem went away.